using backticks in rsyslog config - unable to access file
rsyslog 8.2312.0 on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I need to include a license number in a rsyslog record. The license number exists in the file /mydir/license.txt.
Using backticks seem to fit the bill, but I can't get them to work.
The file is world-readable and running the backtick command from the bash prompt works OK as an unprivileged user.
# ll /mydir/license.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16 Nov  4 16:48 /mydir/license.txt
# echo `cat /mydir/license.txt`
MY-LICENSE-CODE

I am following this tutorial and have added an extra field to the end:
template(name="json-template" type="list" option.jsonf="on") {
    property(outname="@timestamp" name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" format="jsonf")
    property(outname="host" name="hostname" format="jsonf")
    property(outname="severity" name="syslogseverity" caseConversion="upper" format="jsonf" datatype="number")
    property(outname="facility" name="syslogfacility" format="jsonf" datatype="number")
    property(outname="syslog-tag" name="syslogtag" format="jsonf")
    property(outname="source" name="app-name" format="jsonf" onEmpty="null")
    property(outname="message" name="msg" format="jsonf")
    constant(outname="environment" value="dev" format="jsonf")
    constant(outname="license" value=`cat /mydir/license.txt` format="jsonf" )
}

When I restart the rsyslog service, I get the following error in syslog where line 27 is that cat command.
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/51-rsyslog-logify.conf, on or before line 27: file could not be accessed for `cat /mydir/license.txt` [v8.2312.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

and the resulting logged records show
"license": "\/* file cound not be accessed - seeerror messages *\/"

I have also tried putting the license file in the same directory as the config file and used absolute and relative paths to find it there, but no joy.
Apparmor is running, but I don't see any errors in syslog related to this problem.
If I change the cat for an echo command, it echoes the file path correctly, so it seems to be a problem with the file access, but I'm stumped as to what the problem is.

A thought - the syslog service runs as the syslog user, which has no shell.  is that the problem?

rsyslog does not actually run a cat command when you use the backticks, it just skips 4 chars and opens that string as filename. Make sure you have no extra spaces or non-printing chars in the string. You can strace -f -o /tmp/out rsyslogd and it should be clear what system call is being used on what filename, eg openat(..., "filename", O_RDONLY) = 4, and the following newfstatat() and read(). Note the rsyslogd usually changes to dir / at the start. Test with -C to not do this.

Thanks. I was getting 275:83226 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/mydir/license.txt", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied) .
I moved the file to /etc/rsyslog.d and it worked. ( I thought I'd tried that before).
I would like to be able to read from /mydir, though.  I'm doing this test as root, all locations owned by root and the dir and file are other-readable. Any thoughts as to why I'm getting permission denied?

The problem is solved enough to close.
As suggested by @meuh,  I used strace to see what was happening, and I was getting a Permission denied error.
I have even tried preventing rsyslog from dropping to a non-privileged user so that it's always running as root, but no joy.
It works ok if the file is in the config folder for rsyslog. I have created a symlink to the "real" file in the target directory and it's working OK.
In an ideal world, I'd be able to read from anywhere, but I'm moving on.
